# Discrepancies in clock.tick()?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am really new to this website so please bear with me. I am currently working on a doodle-jump like game for a school project and I am having trouble getting the player to jump up and down consistently. The problem is that if the line of command for the jump gets executed for more than a couple seconds, it starts to get inconsistent (not landing at the right height, jump distance decreases...). The only thing I can think of that could be causing this inconsistency is the `clock.tick()` function. Please note that you'd have to press space to initiate the process. Any advice on bettering the game and tips on unit collision and getting the screen to "move up" as the player progresses is also welcome. Once again I apologize as I am an absolute novice at pygame and this site.

```
bif = "Background.jpg"
mif = "Ball.png"
import pygame, sys
import random
import os
from pygame.locals import*
import time

class Ball(object):

    def __init__(self):
        x = 320
        y = 460
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0
        self.g = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,16,16)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.dx
        self.rect.y += self.dy
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0

    def aground(self):
        if self.g <= 500:
            return True
        elif self.g > 500:
            return False

    def moveleft(self):
        if self.rect.x > 640:
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 640
            self.dx = (-(speed*seconds))
            self.update()

    def moveright(self):
        if self.rect.x > 640:
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 640
        self.dx = (speed*seconds)
        self.update()

    def jump(self):
        if self.g == 1000:
            self.g = 0
        if self.aground() == True:
            self.dy = -(speed*seconds)
            self.g += 1
            self.update()
        elif self.aground() == False:
            self.dy = (speed*seconds)
            self.g += 1
            self.update()


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),0,32)
background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
ball = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()
x = 0
a = 0
y = 480
player = Ball()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
speed = 1000
j = 0
start = 0
init = 0

while True:

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.moveleft()
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.moveright()
    if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        init = 1

    if init == 1:
        player.jump()

    milli = clock.tick()
    seconds = milli/1000.

    if a%10 == 0:
        pygame.draw.rect(background,(140,240,130), Rect((x,y),(70,30)))

    a +=12
    x = random.randint(0,640)
    y -= 15

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255, 200, 0),player.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Instead of... whatever crazy system that is for jumping, you implement a proper gravity system, e.g. 1) Jumping works if you are on the ground, and sets your upward velocity to Y 2) Every frame, you go up by Y, but Y is decreased by gravity, G 3) If you collided with a floor, then you are now grounded - set Y to 0 and stop changing it, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patashu mentioned, it would make much more sense to be using a gravity system to handle your jumps.  Here are some snippets from one of my own pygame projects to give you an idea of how it could work:

```
 def update(self):

        self.find_state()
        self.find_move()
        self.do_move()

        if not(self.onGround):      # player is in the air
            self.playerForces.append(Player.gravity)
            if self.primary_state == PlayerState.JUMPFORWARD:
                self.playerVel[0] = self.walkingSpeed * (-1 if self.facing_left else 1)
            elif self.primary_state == PlayerState.JUMPBACKWARD:
                self.playerVel[0] = self.backSpeed * (1 if self.facing_left else -1)
        else:                       # player is on the ground
            if self.secondary_state == PlayerState.WALKING:
                self.playerVel[0] = self.walkingSpeed * (-1 if self.facing_left else 1)
            elif self.secondary_state == PlayerState.BACKING:
                self.playerVel[0] = self.backSpeed * (1 if self.facing_left else -1)
            else:
                self.playerVel[0] = 0

            # first frame of jumping
            if self.primary_state == PlayerState.JUMPING:
                self.playerForces.append([0, -self.jumpHeight])
                self.onGround = False

        self.apply_forces()

        self.playerForces = list() # after applying forces for this frame, clear the list
```

You can see that my `Player` class has a flag called `onGround`.  This gets set to `False` when the player jumps, and is used to determine whether or not to apply a gravity force to the `Player` object.  By doing this, the `Player.jumpHeight` value might start off at say 10 (which means move up 10 pixels per frame), and every frame that the `Player` is in the air, that amount gets reduced by a certain amount (the gravity value).  Eventually gravity will overcome the force from jumping and the `Player` will begin heading back towards the ground.

In another portion of my code, I have a `pygame.Rect` object for the `Player` object, and for the "ground".  I check if they have collided, and if they have, I change the `Player`'s `onGround` flag back to `True` so that it will stop applying gravit to it:

```
 if playerRect.colliderect(ground):
        collisionShift = gameUtils.getMinTransVect(playerRect, ground)
        player1.playerForces.append([0, collisionShift[1]])
        player1.onGround = True
        player1.playerVel[1] = 0
```

As you may be able to see from that, I also make a small "correction" to the location of the `Player` object after the collision.  This ensures that every time the `Player` "lands" on the ground, it won't be "sunken" in at all.  That can happen if in one frame an object moves more pixels in a direction than there are between two collideable objects (so if there is a 4 pixel gap between the `Player` object and the ground, and the `Player` moves 8 pixels downward in one frame.  In that situation, if you simply stop moving the `Player` after the collision is detected, it will be sort of sunken into the ground).